# How do you add a for loop directive to cylce through an array in VueJS whilst using CLI3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using Vue CLI and have very basic routing set up to fetch two Views. One called Home and the other called Teams. I am ready to add a for loop directive within my project to loop through the list of teams. However, I am unsure on where it goes. My main.js is now as below; Idealy the array would be on my view file but it also dosn't work when located there. I could try adding it to a Component, but I can't get a Component into a View either. Any help welcome. In addition I have created a CodeSandBox https://codesandbox.io/s/2wvv5k8v2n

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const clubs = [
  {
    name: "Tigers",
    location: "Manchester",
    members: "22"
  },
  {
    name: "Dolphins",
    location: "Miami",
    members: "19"
  },
  {
    name: "Bleu Sox",
    location: "Paris",
    members: "13"
  }
];

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    club: clubs
  }
});

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: if i understood well you want to loop trough list of teams, on team page. you can do it in views/teams.vue or you can do it in components/compName.vue and then import component in views/teams and register it and render it. Data can be in file that you use data in loop, or it can be in vuex store. Clubs array should not be in main.js becuase you are not using it there.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I am wanting to do. I feel like placing the array in a component rather than the view my be slightly better, to help separate data in a way that makes it more managable etc. However, I am stuck with how you import this component into a view and get the for loop working. I have removed the array from main.js in my CodeSandBox based on your advice.

Comment: when you import component you need to register it, you can see example in docs.

Comment: here are some examples, you should register it localy https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

Comment: This now works. Thank you so much for your help and support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better not to have data in main.js. Create a separate folder called data and import the data to your teams component script section and use through that. Below forked and updated codesandbox is one way to do it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/z6zlpk18mx

Comment: This is great. Your fork really helped me understand better. Much appriciated :)